# Change authentication method (password + username) to intranet AD (classic asp)

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic, active-directory, intranet

I have a project where an Admin creates a questionnaire to every user of the company should answer.
However this project have a problem. the admin needs create new user + password. But it's insane create for a thousands of employees...

it's simple change/adpat this project to instead the user insert his credentials the system detect the user nt-logged info and shows one page but if not shows only the questionnaire to submit?

aditional notes: this is for working in company intranet

Comment: Try looking at the `Request.ServerVariables()` method for NT usernames and passwords: `Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER")` should give you any NT/AD authenticated users in Classic ASP. However, beware of IIS - you'll need to ensure that the application's authentication mode is set to **Windows Authentication**.

Comment: windows authentication I have set to enable and anonymous disable

Answer (score 0):

So, to clarify, try picking up the `AUTH_USER`:

```vbs
Dim authUser
authUser = Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER")
...
```

This cab be stored in the database as your user's unique identifier. Beware of accounts that are generic (i.e. multiple users using a single account).